# Increase Session timeout after user wants to extend a Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

After user login I am set user data ,Session timeout0,SessionTimeoutDate in Session.Just like that  where SeessionHelper.LoggedUser has user Data.

```
SessionHelper.LoggedInUser.SessionTimeout = HttpContext.Session.Timeout;
                    SessionHelper.LoggedInUser.SessionWillExpireOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(HttpContext.Session.Timeout);
```

this session value i get in html page for interval.

And in js i am setting interval to continuously checking current date is greater than SessionWillExpireOn if is there means session timeout i open up pop up which has two button Extend session and terminate session. If user click extend button  Then I called Ajax to increase session timeout just like this.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
    myVar = setInterval(checkSession, 500);

    $('#btnExtend').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/SetSession",
            cache: false,
            async: true
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log('1');
            myVar = setInterval(checkSession, 500);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log('2');
        });
    });
});

function checkSession() {
    if (new Date(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')) > new Date(moment(SessionWillExpireOn).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'))) {
        console.log('Session expried');
        $('#SessionExpireModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
```

Extend function increase session by 2 mintues

```
 HttpContext.Session.Timeout = 2;
            SessionHelper.LoggedInUser.SessionTimeout = HttpContext.Session.Timeout;
            SessionHelper.LoggedInUser.SessionWillExpireOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(HttpContext.Session.Timeout);
```

It will increase session timeout after that success of setSession method after that  i started interval to check sessionTimeout.
 My main question is it is Best way to increase sessiontimeout or it is something else that  i can reduce my code. Beacause  after Extend button click it will call setSession Method will increase Session value and SessionTimeOut. But in My interval function i get sessionTimeout of previous value not current updated once. How to overcome this Problem so that i get updated session timeout value in Interval Function.
Any Suggestion.

Comment: Got a solution.